# Rails - how to make a condition with "has_many" association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have these two models:

**car**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colors
end
```

**Color**

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Every car can have many colors.
What I am trying to do - to fetch all cars that don't have black colors.

Is there any way to do it in one query with using ActiveRecord? I can do it this way:

```
@cars = Car.where('brand = ?', params[:car])
@cars.each do |car|
  car.colors.each do |color|
    ...test that the color is not black...
  end
end
```

But this method is a bit slow... is there a faster approach of doing this with one query?

Thank you

Comment: What attributes does `Color` have?

Comment: @NickVeys `name`, `position`, just these two.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the attributes on your `Color` model, but something like this is what you're looking for:

```
@cars = Car.where('brand = ?', params[:car])
@cars = @cars.joins(:colors)
             .where("colors.name <> 'black'").each do |car|
```

Or, if you're using Rails 4:

```
@cars = Car.where('brand = ?', params[:car])
@cars = @cars.joins(:colors)
             .where.not(colors: { name: :black }).each do |car|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Car.joins(:colors).where("colors.name <> 'black'").group('cars.id')
```

UPDATE:

You can probably do this in two queries

```
black_car_ids = Color.where(:name => 'black').pluck('DISTINCT car_id')
@cars = Car.where("id not in (?)", black_car_ids).where('brand = ?', params[:car])
```

Comment: Thank you `Vimsha` for your answer. But for example, if the colors are `red`, `blue`, `black` and `green`, it still returns the brand. But I would need to check if - for example - Audi doesn't have black color, then return it, if one of colors is black, then don't return it. How to do this?